# Xcode Build failed,fatal error: module 'firebase_auth' not found @import firebase_auth;

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, flutter, cocoapods

```
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

\\\Error Message

```
     ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/Razi/Desktop/projects/Sayy/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'firebase_auth' not found
    @import firebase_auth;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

I have tried deleting Podfile/Podlock and running `pod init`/ `pod install` without success. Also have reviewed the GitHub repo for ios folder. Why is firebase_auth not found?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue only when trying to archive. It works fine in debug mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: I was able to eventually find a workaround by executing the following:

1. Running `Flutter Clean` (in ios folder of project)
2. Deleting both `Podlock` & `Pod Folder`
3. Running `pod init` followed by `pod install`

seems to be an issue with the runner.xcworkspace folder and the build
files needed to run builds.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to follow suggested steps of executing `Flutter clean`, manually removing `podfile` and `podfile.lock` along with `Pod` related folders, executing `pod install` again, etc. - nothing helped.

What helped me in the end was the following sequence:

1. Create a new project with same dependencies declared in the `pubspec.yaml`.
2. Run `pub get` in the new project.
3. Run `pod install` in the new project to get everything generated
4. Copy newly generated `podfile` and `podfile.lock` files to the old project.
5. Run `pod install` in the old project.

Only after this sequence I was able to build the iOS project again.

Comment: monster !  the only way I could restore my installation after a long research

Comment: I am facing this issue but can't find any solution  tried all the steps

Answer (score 4):

```
These steps helped me to resolve the issue completely for IOS:
>> flutter clean
 then "delete podfile, podfile.lock, pod folder"
>> flutter pub get
>> pod install
>> flutter run
```

Answer (score 2):

1. It seems like you provided not a full Podfile's content (I can't see anything about Sayy target there) or you've been changing Podfile
2. Depending on what you trying to archive either remove last 3 lines in Podfile or move line "pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'" to target 'Runner' right after 'use_modular_headers!'
3. open XCode toppest item in left sidebar (blue icon) -> in leftest menu you will see two sections — Project and Targets. So names that are in 'targets' block — is the only one that can appear in Podfile after keyword 'target'
4. everything depends on:

- do you need AFNetworking?
- what targets do you have in your application

Answer (score 2):

I have got rid of this issue buy un-commenting the line in Podfile

```
 platform :ios, '10.0'
```

Also delete clean your project and rebuild again!

Answer (score 1):

Change the Deployment target for ios either in build settings-> Deployment in xcode or in podfile set deployment target greater than 10

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me

1. Find the latest version of firebase_core / firebase_auth on pub.dev
2. Clear your `Pods/` and `Podfile.lock` in the `ios` folder
3. Run `pod install --repo-update` in the `ios` folder (IMPORTANT!)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps which worked for me:

1. Delete ios > `Pods`
2. Delete ios > `Podfile`, `Podfile.lock`
3. flutter clean
4. flutter run

After executing these three commands in this order, pod install started, and it was done.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that fixed it for me was creating a project in a local, non-cloud based folder. After that I was able to copy the files and imports over, follow the pods processes (Delete ios > `Pods`,
Delete ios > `Podfile`, Delete ios > `Podfile.lock`, `flutter clean`, `flutter run`) and run it in the local version and it worked fine.