# Flutter trying to installing packages

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies

No matter which package I tried to install when running on iOS simulator get an error the same no matter which package.

fatal error: module 'name of the module I'm trying' not found

Is a new MacBook Air, so I can't emulate Android to see if is the same.

Been days stuck here

This is the output:

> Failed to build iOS app Error output from Xcode build: ↳
> objc[94975]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x1faf938f0) and ?? (0x11acac2b8). One of the two will be
> used. Which one is undefined.
> objc[94975]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x1faf93940) and ?? (0x11acac308). One of the two will be used. Which
> one is undefined.
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> Xcode's output: ↳
> /Users/rafy/Desktop/Flutter_App_with_Android_Studio/cte_baberia/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9:
> fatal error: module 'firebase_auth' not found
> @import firebase_auth;
> ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.
> note: Using new build system
> note: Building targets in parallel
> note: Planning build
> note: Constructing build description
> warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To
> resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in
> target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
>
> Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching
> application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

Comment: Did you tried flutter clean There is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/62585428/13819909 Try that and see if the problem still exist

Answer (score 0):

Please run a `flutter clean` and then post the outputs when you run these commands:

```
pub get
```

and

```
flutter build ios
```

Comment: ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
   
    error: No profiles for 'com.rafaelvazquez.cteBaberia' were found: Xcode couldn't find
    any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching
    'com.rafaelvazquez.cteBaberia'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate
    a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.
    (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Encountered error while building for device.

Comment: This happen when I rely to add a package, if no package is add to yml it works fine